# How to access static variables in methods using Swift's 'abstract class'-like protocol extensions

Tags: swift, polymorphism, abstract-class, swift-extensions, swift-protocols

I've been trying to make abstract superclass-like behaviour in Swift using the protocols and extensions suggested here: [Abstract classes in Swift Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110396/abstract-classes-in-swift-language)
But I can't figure out how to write methods that make use of static (class) variables.  For example, if I want to get the perimeter of an abstract shape class:

```
protocol Shape {
    static var numSides: Int {get}
    var sideLength: Double {get}
}
class Triangle: Shape {
    static var numSides: Int = 3
    var sideLength: Double
    init (sideLength: Double) { self.sideLength = sideLength }
}
class Square: Shape {
    static var numSides: Int = 4
    var sideLength: Double
    init (sideLength: Double) { self.sideLength = sideLength }
}
extension Shape {
    func calcPerimeter() -> Double {
    return sideLength * Double(numSides)
    }
}
```

Swift doesn't want me to use static var numSides in the calcPerimeter method.  I know that if I made it an instance variable the code would run, but this doesn't seem like the right way to go.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use numSide as a static variable not instance one. 
You cannot call Shape.numSides but you can use `Self` keyword which reference to the concrete class.
Try this:

```
Self.numSides
```

Comment: Not self but Self.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the Self in my answer is uppercase.