# Overriding superclass initializer in Swift

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, singleton, overriding, initializer

I've found numerous examples for using the Singleton pattern in Swift 3. I'm trying to use this method:

```
class Records: RailsData {
    static let shared = Records()
    private init() {} 
    ...
}
```

When I do, I get the compiler error:

> Overriding declaration requires an 'override' keyword

When I add the `override` keyword, it compiles and everything seems to work. Is the override needed because I'm subclassing `RailsData`? `RailData` is an abstract class in that it is not instantiated directly. I also didn't make it a *singleton*.

I'm trying to make sure I don't get bit later by using the `override` modifier...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong ;) The `override` modifier is *required* because your `RailsData` superclass declares a *designated initializer* with the *exact* same signature:

```swift
class RailsData {
    init() {...}
    ...
}
```

as such, the `override` modified is made necessary in your subclass. The same thing applies to inherited methods as well. From the [The Swift Programming Language book](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID221):

> When you write a subclass initializer that matches a superclass designated initializer, you are effectively providing an override of that designated initializer. Therefore, you must write the `override` modifier before the subclass’s initializer definition. This is true even if you are overriding an automatically provided default initializer.
>
> As with an overridden property, method or subscript, the presence of the override modifier prompts Swift to check that the superclass has a matching designated initializer to be overridden, and validates that the parameters for your overriding initializer have been specified as intended.

Rest assured, you won't be bitten by this later on ;)

---

**Motivating example**. To see this *initializer overriding* in action, try this example:

```swift
class SuperClass {
    init(x: Int) {
        print("3. SuperClass.init(x: \(x))")
    }
    convenience init() {
        print("1. SuperClass.init()")
        self.init(x: 123) // Will be overridden by subclass.
    }
}

class SubClass: SuperClass {
    override init(x: Int) {
        print("2. SubClass.init(x: \(x))")
        super.init(x: x)
        print("4. SubClass.init(x: \(x))")
    }
}

// Calls inherited convenience initializer.
let sub = SubClass()
```

outputs:

> 1. SuperClass.init()
> 2. SubClass.init(x: 123)
> 3. SuperClass.init(x: 123)
> 4. SubClass.init(x: 123)

---

**Abstract classes**. By the way, there is no direct, linguistic support for *abstract classes* in [Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24110512/819340) — nor in [Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1034464/819340) — but at least [Cupertino is thinking about it](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0026-abstract-classes-and-methods.md) ;) Currently, such a concept is merely a *soft* convention used by frameworks authors, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Paulo Matteo's comprehensive answer, this is most likely the fix you need:

```swift
override private init() {
    super.init()
}
```