# "Standard simple" interfaces in Java?

Tags: android, interface

So here in Java I've written a typical class, to send json to a rest server.  (I'll include the whole class below for clarity.) So that's a file **"Fetcher.java"**

Now for the callback you need an interface.  The interface is trivial, just one function with a string.

```
public interface FetcherInterface {
    public void fetcherDone(String result);
}
```

Annoyingly you need a whole file for that, **"FetcherInterface.java"**

So this interface is nothing but "one callback with a string".  Often all you need is just "one callback with no arguments".

In fact ........ **are there some sort of standard interfaces I can use**, or something like that?

It seems kind of annoying to have to put in a whole interface for such a simple "standard" interface.

What's the deal on this?  What's the javaly solution?

It seems you **CAN NOT put it in the same file**:

[image]

Perhaps I misunderstand something there.  If you could put it in the same file, that would be convenient at least.

(Lambdas are not yet practically available. Anyway, sometimes you want an interface.)

---

Just for clarity, here's how you call the class

```
    JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
    try {
        j.put("height", 2.1);
        j.put("width", 2.5);
        j.put("command", "blah");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    new Fetcher("mobile/login", j, new FetcherInterface() {
                @Override
                public void fetcherDone(String result) {
                    Log.d("DEV","all done");
                    doSomething(result);
                }
        }
    ).execute();
```

or indeed

```
public class HappyClass extends Activity implements FetcherInterface {
...

private void someCall() {
    JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
    try {
        j.put("height", 2.1);
        j.put("width", 2.5);
        j.put("command", "blah");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    new Fetcher("mobile/data", j, this).execute();
    devBlank();
}

@Override
public void fetcherDone(String result) {
    Log.d("DEV","all done" +result);
    doSomething(result);
}
```

Here's the whole class...  Fetcher.java file

```
public class Fetcher extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private String urlTail;
    private JSONObject jsonToSend;
    private FetcherInterface callback;

    // initializer...
    Fetcher(String ut, JSONObject toSend, FetcherInterface cb) {
        urlTail = ut;
        jsonToSend = toSend;
        callback = cb;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null; // declare outside try, to close in finally
        BufferedReader reader = null;           // declare outside try, to close in finally
        String rawJsonResultString = null;
        String json = jsonToSend.toString();

        Log.d("DEV","the json string in Fetcher is " +json);

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://falcon.totalfsm.com/" + urlTail);

            Log.d("DEV","the full URL in Fetcher is " +url);

            // open a json-in-the-body type of connection.......
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            // urlConnection.setDoOutput(false); // can be important?

            urlConnection.connect();

            OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            os.write(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            os.close();

            // annoyingly, you have to choose normal versus error stream...
            InputStream inputStream;
            int status = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                inputStream = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
            else
                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            if (inputStream == null) { // nothing to do.
                return null;
            }

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { // adding newlines makes debugging easier
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) { // stream was empty
                return null;
            }

            rawJsonResultString = buffer.toString();
            return rawJsonResultString;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ", e);
            return null;
        } finally{
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        Log.d("DEV", "Fetcher done");
        if (s==null) {
            Log.d("DEV","applying anti-null measures in Fetcher!");
            s = "message from app communications layer: 'null' returned from servers for that call at " +urlTail;
        }
        callback.fetcherDone(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: According to [the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html), Android supports lambdas. You need to do a little extra work if you are targeting API level 23 or lower.

Comment: Hi Ted, thanks, as I mention I appreciate lambdas are a coming-possibility. Do you know is there an answer to my question about interfaces?  Are there maybe "standard interfaces" or something like that?

Comment: `Annoyingly you need a whole file for that, "FetcherInterface.java"` Not necessarily. You can put the class inside another Java file, i.e.: an Activity class.

Comment: Maybe you could make it `protected`  or `static`, instead of `public`.

Comment: If you want a public interface, it goes in its own file. That's how Java works.

Comment: I use `protected interface` to declare my interface **inside** my class.

Comment: @JoeBlow Not sure what you're asking. There are interfaces that you *may* be able to re-purpose, or libraries that encompass the functionality you've written. In general, unless it's specifically intended for the purpose you describe, I'd stick to defining your app interfaces yourself, because things change.

Comment: that's a fantastic tip @Rotwang, thanks.   In many cases that seems to be good idiom.  It's a potentially a bit annoying that you then have to `implements Fetcher.ThatName` but yeah, awesome.

Comment: hi @DaveNewton.  Fine, that makes perfect sense.  Good one.

Comment: For me the definitive answer here == "If you want a public interface, it goes in its own file. That's how Java works." + "For a local interface, use protected interface inside the class, implementing ClassName.InterfaceName"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel bad answering my own question, but as there were no other answers this info may be helpful.

DaveNewton and Rowtang have supplied the exact answers here:

(Point 1) If you want a genuinely **public** interface, it goes in its own file. That's how Java works. There's no alternative.

(Point 2) Normally, use `protected interface` and declare the interface **inside** the class. It can then be used throughout the app.

So...

```
public class Fetcher extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    protected interface FetcherInterface {
        public void fetcherDone(String result);
    }

    private String urlTail;
    private JSONObject jsonToSend;
    private FetcherInterface callback;

    Fetcher(String ut, JSONObject toSend, FetcherInterface cb) {
        urlTail = ut;
        jsonToSend = toSend;
        callback = cb;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    ....
```

(c# programmers would maybe call it "IFetcher".)