# How to port a complicated abstract class to swift?

Tags: swift

I have an abstract class in my mind and I can't implement its several features in swift, so I use C++ to deliver my thoughts:

```
template <class T>
class Swapping {
public:
    void swap() { _foregroundIndex = backgroundIndex() }
    virtual void cleanup() = 0;
    T* foreground() { return _buffer[foregroundIndex()]; }
    T* background() { return _buffer[backgroundIndex()]; }
    void setForeground(T* foreground) { _buffer[foregroundIndex()] = foreground; }
    void setBackground(T* background) { _buffer[backgroundIndex()] = background; }
private: 
    short foregroundIndex() { return _foregroundIndex; } 
    short backgroundIndex() { return _foregroundIndex ^ 1; }
    short _foregroundIndex = 0;
    T* _buffer[2] = {NULL, NULL};
}
```

The main contradiction is that

1. The pure virtual method `cleanup()` requires all subclasses to implement it explicitly (can achieve in swift with `protocol`)
2. The instance variable `_foregroundIndex` has an initial value (**cannot** achieve using `protocol`)
3. The instance variable `_foregroundIndex` is restricted to be `private` ( **cannot** achieve using `protocol`)

On the other hand, if I use a `class` instead of `protocol`, then I can't guarantee `cleanup()` method is overriden.

One may suggest that put the virtual method in a `protocol` and the instance variable in a `class`. That may work but is not a obsession-satisfying one.

P.S. Objective-C is not Swift. Any `objc_runtime` related workaround is not preferred.

Comment: Swift doesn't support abstract class and [plans for it has been defered](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0026-abstract-classes-and-methods.md). There's no perfect workaround in Swift, see the discussion in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111356/swift-class-method-which-must-be-overridden-by-subclass)

Comment: Thinking about an answer, it seems to me as you are mixing implementation details with APIs. A protocol is just supposed to express the public API that can be used, to express a set of functionality. `_foregroundIndex`, however, is an implementation detail. Why would the protocol care about how a class implements the functionality described in the protocol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s an obvious solution, which I have seen often but will certainly not satisfy you is:

```
func cleanup() {
    fatalError("You must override cleanup()")
}
```

Then you could try using `extension`s to extend the protocol with default implementations, but extensions don’t allow stored properties and so you would most likely need some external objects or other magic you certainly also dislike.

As I noted above in the comments, you might need to rethink your design. I don’t know what you really intend to do, but maybe something like this would work out for you:

```
class Swapper<T> {
    private var foregroundIndex = 0
    private var backgroundIndex: Int {
        return foregroundIndex ^ 1
    }
    private var buffer: [T?] = [nil, nil]

    private let cleanupHandler: () -> ()

    init(cleanupHandler: @escaping () -> ()) {
        self.cleanupHandler = cleanupHandler
    }

    func cleanup() {
        cleanupHandler()
    }

    var foreground: T? {
        get {
            return buffer[foregroundIndex]
        }
        set {
            buffer[foregroundIndex] = newValue
        }
    }
    var background: T? {
        get {
            return buffer[backgroundIndex]
        }
        set {
            buffer[backgroundIndex] = newValue
        }
    }

    func swap() {
        foregroundIndex = backgroundIndex
    }
}
```

This makes more sense to me as this allows any types to be swapped with any clean up handler, without having to subclass the class every time.