# Force child view controllers to call a base view controller method

Tags: ios, swift, oop

I need to post a notification on viewDidLoad of every one of my ViewControllers. I have a BaseViewController with a `postNotification` method, and it gets an enum as a parameter to identify the screen. It looks like this

```
class BaseViewController {

    func postNotification(for screen: ScreenName) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notification,
                                        object: nil,
                                        userInfo: ["ScreenName": screen])
    }
}

class AViewController: BaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        postNotification(for: screenA)
    }
}

class BViewController: BaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        postNotification(for: screenB)
    }
}
```

Suppose we need to add another view controller later in the future, such as `CViewController`. I want to force the developer of `CViewController` to call this postNotification method with screen enum.

What is the best practice to achieve this on Swift?

**Edit**

Thanks to Loren's suggestion, I added a protocol on my base class

```
typealias BaseController = BaseViewController & BaseProtocol

protocol BaseProtocol {
    var screenName: ScreenName { get }
}
```

This forces all my viewcontrollers to conform protocol and initialize `screenName`, but now I can't get it from my `BaseViewController`. If I can get child view controller's `screenName` property from `BaseViewController`, I would eliminate calling `postNotification` method on each child, and call it only on BaseViewController

Comment: Does this link help (about 3/4 down)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111356/swift-class-method-which-must-be-overridden-by-subclass/24481555

Comment: Hey thanks! It kinda helped, but created another problem. I updated my question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    var screenName: ScreenName!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let screenName = self.screenName {
            self.postNotification(for: screenName)
        } else {
            fatalError("screenName must be instantiated")
        }
    }

    func postNotification(for screen: ScreenName) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notification,
                                        object: nil,
                                        userInfo: ["ScreenName": screen])
    }
}

class AViewController: BaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.screenName = screenA
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

class BViewController: BaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.screenName = screenB
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Try this since you are using inheritance, have BaseViewController inherit UIViewController superclass, then create a screenName variable. In your childViewControllers instantiate the screenName before calling `super.viewDidLoad()`. You can use protocols like you mentioned to force the implementation of the variable, but it just seems like overkill for just one variable.

Comment: This doesn't solve my initial problem. Developer can add CViewController and forget to set screenName in your solution. I want to force (give compile time error) developer to change screenName.

Comment: I added a fatalError() when safely unwrapping the screenName variable when calling `postNotification` in `viewDidLoad` of the `BaseViewController`. `super.viewDidLoad` will always be called

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer, but this gives a Runtime error. I still believe there should be a solution that gives compile time error