# Is a blank function conventional in subclass that conforms to custom protocol?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, subclass, swift-protocols

I have two main screens in my app, currently both just subclasses of `UIViewController`. These two view controllers are very similar - they both implement my custom subclass of `UIView` called `HeaderView` that is responsible for displaying information and taking user input. As it stands, this code is repetitive because the `HeaderView` setup is the same for both view controllers - the only difference is what happens when the user confirms the text entry in `HeaderView`.

To cut down on repetitive code, I am creating a class called `InputViewController` (a subclass of `UIViewController`) that houses the aspects of the two view controllers that are identical. Eventually, I want the two view controllers to subclass `InputViewController` instead of `UIViewController`.

```
class InputViewController: UIViewController, InputProtocol {

    private let headerView = HeaderView()
        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // layout, etc.
        setupCallbacks()
    }
    
    internal func setupCallbacks() {
        headerView.onUpdate = { (text: String) in
            // called when user confirms text entry in headerView
            self.onHeaderUpdate()
        }
    }
    
    internal func onHeaderUpdate() {} // Blank function
    
}
```

`setupCallbacks()` and `onHeaderUpdate()` are methods defined in the protocol that the `InputViewController` conforms to. The `HeaderView` implements a callback closure that is handled in `setupCallbacks()` by `headerView.onUpdate...`

The protocol that `InputViewController` conforms to:

```
protocol InputProtocol {
    func setupCallbacks()
    func onHeaderUpdate()
}
```

To illustrate this, I drew up a diagram;
[image: diagram]

Since I want the subclasses of `InputViewController` to override the `onHeaderUpdate()` method, is it conventional to leave the definition of `onHeaderUpdate()` in `InputViewController` blank or is there another solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it conventional to leave the definition of `onHeaderUpdate()` in `InputViewController` blank

Yes, that is called an *abstract method.* It is common to give it code that crashes deliberately, as a way of saying, “I exist only to be overridden in a subclass.”

(I should go further and say that what you are creating, a base view controller that carries out initial configurations that all subclasses must implement, is also normal.)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! I struggled to find answers on Google and SO because I wasn't familiar with the abstract method term. May be helpful to include this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110362/abstract-functions-in-swift-language

Comment: As I’ve now pointed out in my answer, a base view controller that carries out initial configurations that all subclasses must implement is also normal. You have reinvented a very useful wheel! In some of my apps, all my view controllers do this. They all inherit and implement abstract configuration methods to set up views, colors, constraints, and so on, which are called by the base view controller.

Comment: Awesome, it's good to know that my assumptions were normal and not completely wrong. This method of implementation is very helpful in reducing code and improving readability at the same time. All good things!