How to define a container of interfaces?
In other languages it is common to define containers of interfaces for many design patterns. I understand that in Swift, interfaces are implemented as protocols. However, I'm struggling with making this simple code snippet work:
protocol Item: AnyObject {
}

class Container<Value> where Value: AnyObject {
}

let test = Container<Item>()

The compiler complains that:

'Container' requires that 'any Item' be a class type

Having done some research, it is often suggested to use a specific implementation of the Item protocol as the type parameter for Container, like
class ConcreteItem: Item {
}

let test = Container<ConcreteItem>()

However, this foils the idea of having a container of different types: There might be another class ConcreteItem2 whose implementation is totally unrelated to the implementation of ConcreteItem, but that conforms to the same interface.
So how what is the clean way of making this work in Swift?

Edit: I was asked to add a more practical example. The motivation can be to implement the observer pattern. So I would have a protocol for the observer:
protocol Observer: AnyObject {
    func modelChanged(modelData: DataClass)
}

However, implementations of the observer can be completely unrelated, so it would be strange to implement a base class for them. Still the container for the observers should only accept objects of Observer type.

as u don't have abstract classes which u can use as generic types maybe u can try abstract functions , have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110362/abstract-functions-in-swift-language/

Can you give a specific and practical example of what you want to do? You should not try to translate, word by word, from another language.

Swift does not require you to use classes and class-polymorphism to solve problems, like it is in class oriented languages, even though there are classes and class-polymorphism. In Swift, type parameters in generics, are concrete types (structs, enums, primitives, final classes and also - but rarely - open classes). You can write complete programs without using a single class. In Swift, use cases where you would use classes in other languages are actually more often Actors and should be implemented as such, rather than as classes in the realm of OOP.

@Sweeper I have added a more specific example.

@CouchDeveloper This means, following OOP design patterns might be not very swifty after all?

"This means, following OOP design patterns might be not very swifty after all" Exactly.

As Sweeper said ;)  I also accepted the answer from @Tiran Ut, because it is in alignment of your solution. However, there are probably better solutions for your specific problem. You might add, what you are trying to accomplish :)

Observer Pattern -  while I think, these well known patterns, originally discovered by the GoF and written down in their book, are still useful as of today, a "swift" implementation would not start with defining base classes employing OO analysis and then coming up with probably an abstract factory, that creates these classes, and then further refine the solution for several use cases with another factory which creates an abstract factory which uses dependency injection and configurations files.  No, just use Swift Combine. ;)

@kostrykin I still don't see how you will use the container in the observer implementation. If you need to loop through a set of observers and notify them you can just put them inside any collection (eg array) and the do that. Like [Observer]().forEach { $0.modelChanged(model) }. No need to have a wrapper for that.
There's a use case for a wrapper though that I use quite often that is a weak reference container. Smth like the one mentioned here

@TiranUt The point is that I need a collection of weak references, thus the wrapper. It is generally discouraged to use strong references for observers.

@kostrykin Ok, that's exactly what is mentioned in the article. I also updated my answer

Tbh it is really not clear what you're trying to achieve. You can make your pattern work though by using type erasure.
protocol Item: AnyObject {
}

class Container<Value> where Value: Item { // conform to Item here
}

class AnyItem: Item {} // implement erased type here

let test = Container<AnyItem>()

The other way can be to make a generic container like this:
class Container<Value> {
    private var value: Value

    init(value: Value) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

and then use extensions to add some behavior, for instance:
protocol Cancellable {
    func cancel()
}

extension Container: Cancellable where Value: Cancellable {
    func cancel() {
        value.cancel()
    }
}

UPD:
To make a weak ref container you can do the following:
class Weak<Value: AnyObject> {
    private weak var value: Value?

    init(value: Value?) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

protocol Observer {
    func modelChanged(modelData: DataClass)
}

extension Weak: Observer where Value == Observer {
    func modelChanged(modelData: DataClass) {
        value?.modelChanged(modelData: modelData)
    }
}

And then you can create an array of both weak and strong references:
let observers: [Observer] = [
    Weak(observer),
    yetAnotherObserver,
    ...
]



The compiler complains that:

Your misunderstanding lies in how the Swift type system & generics works.
protocol Item: AnyObject {} defines that all types that fulfill the protocol Item must be a class type.
class Container<Value> where Value: AnyObject {} declares a generic type Container with a type parameter Value which has to conform to the Item protocol and thus has to be a class type (not a value type).
However, at compile time Value must be a single specific type (not a protocol!) because that's how generics work in Swift.
So your code does not mean that a specific Container instance can use any type, a specific Container instance is always bound to a specific Value type.
Consider the following example, just so you understand Swift better, in reality you should never do this:
final class Container<Item> {
    var items = [Item]()
}

// All classes implicitly fulfill the `AnyObject` protocol
final class MyClass1 {}
final class MyClass2 {}

let container = Container<any AnyObject>()
container.items.append(MyClass1())
container.items.append(MyClass2())

Note that the container instance in this case is bound to the specific boxed protocol type (aka 'existential type') for AnyObject.
I.e. at compile time the specific type of the items is any AnyObject and the underlying type information of the elements is lost. If you wanted to access any methods or properties of the instances, you would have to get the type of an element back using type casts:
if let myClass1 = container.items.first as? MyClass1 {
    myClass1.action1()
}

So according to your description what you're actually looking for is what is called 'type erasure'. I.e. a concrete type (not a protocol!) that fulfills a specific protocol and boxes another type that also fulfills the protocol. Just like any AnyObject does.
Type erasure is a non-trivial topic in its own right, on which there are many articles.
AnyHashable from the Swift stdlib is an example of a type erasure implementation. You can view the corresponding code here.
There are different approaches for type erasure, which one is the most suitable for your specific case depends on the specific requirements.
Here is a simple example that may help you:
protocol MyProtocol {
    func test()
}

final class MyClass1: MyProtocol {
    func test() {
        print("Hello World from 'MyClass1'")
    }
}

final class MyClass2: MyProtocol {
    func test() {
        print("Hello World from 'MyClass2'")
    }
}

// A type-erased MyProtocol implementation.
struct AnyMyProtocol: MyProtocol {
    let boxed: any MyProtocol

    init(erasing object: some MyProtocol) {
        boxed = object
    }

    func test() {
        boxed.test()
    }
}

final class Container<Item: MyProtocol> {
    var items = [Item]()
}

let myClass1 = MyClass1()
let myClass2 = MyClass2()

let container = Container<AnyMyProtocol>()
container.items.append(AnyMyProtocol(erasing: myClass1))
container.items.append(AnyMyProtocol(erasing: myClass2))

for object in container.items {
    object.test()
}

In this particular example, you could of course simply implement Container as a non-generic type:
protocol MyProtocol {
    func test()
}

final class MyClass1: MyProtocol {
    func test() {
        print("Hello World from 'MyClass1'")
    }
}

final class MyClass2: MyProtocol {
    func test() {
        print("Hello World from 'MyClass2'")
    }
}

final class Container {
    // Note that 'any MyProtocol' is a concrete boxed type.
    var items = [any MyProtocol]()
}

let myClass1 = MyClass1()
let myClass2 = MyClass2()

let container = Container()
container.items.append(myClass1)
container.items.append(myClass2)

for object in container.items {
    object.test()
}

